# Is it possible to use Spring Restdocs with Jersey application

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jersey-2.0, spring-restdocs

Spring Restdocs is based on Spring MVC Test. So, I wanted to figure out if it's possible to integrate Spring Restdocs with Jersey 2.0 REST application.

If so, could you please point me to any related example or tutorial.

Comment: They're currently working on [restassured support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/tree/rest-assured/spring-restdocs-restassured) which isn't tied to MVC. I imagine this should be released in 1.1.0. I added [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/187) requesting for Jersey Test Framework support, but I don't know how they feel about it. You can leave a comment in the issue if you would like to see support for it.

Comment: @peeskillet, please format your comment as response and I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: UPDATE 2 below: A third-party library has been release for working with Jersey**

They're currently working on [restassured support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/tree/master/spring-restdocs-restassured) which isn't tied to MVC (or any other server framework). I imagine this should be released in 1.1.0. I added a [feature request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/187) for Jersey Test Framework support, but I don't know how they feel about it. You can leave a comment in the issue if you would like to see support for it. But I would imagine them taking the stance that Jersey Test Framework support is not needed, because you can still use REST Assured as the client for your Jersey Test Framework test cases. But we'll see, you never know ;-)

---

#### UPDATE

So not long after this answer was posted, Spring REST Docs merged the rest-assured branch with the master branch, so you can now play around with the SNAPSHOT of the `spring-restdocs-restassured` artifact without needing to build the project yourself. You will just need to add the Spring Snapshot repository. Below is a complete example using Jersey Test Framework.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.restdocs.RestDocumentation;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.requestFields;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.responseFields;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.request.RequestDocumentation.parameterWithName;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.request.RequestDocumentation.pathParameters;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestAssuredRestDocumentation.document;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.restassured.RestAssuredRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration;

/**
 * Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/q/35068860/2587435
 * 
 * Run this like any other JUnit test. The required dependencies are listed below. You will need
 * to add the Spring Snapshot repository, also listed below.
 * 
 * Running the test should produces the following snippets in target/generated-snippets/example-put:
 * 
 * - curl-request.adoc
 * - http-request.adoc
 * - http-response.adoc
 * - path-parameters.adoc
 * - request-fields.adoc
 * - response-fields.adoc
 * 
 * <dependencies>
 *   <dependency>
 *     <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
 *     <artifactId>spring-restdocs-restassured</artifactId>
 *     <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
 *     <scope>test</scope>
 *   </dependency>
 *   <dependency>
 *     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
 *     <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
 *     <version>2.22.1</version>
 *     <scope>test</scope>
 *   </dependency>
 *   <dependency>
 *     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 *     <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
 *     <version>2.22.1</version>
 *     <scope>test</scope>
 *   </dependency>
 *   <dependency>
 *     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
 *     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
 *     <version>1.2</version>
 *     <scope>test</scope>
 *   </dependency>
 *   <dependency>
 *     <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
 *     <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
 *     <version>1.3</version>
 *     <scope>test</scope>
 *   </dependency>
 * </dependencies>
 * 
 * <repositories>
 *   <repository>
 *     <id>spring-snapshots</id>
 *     <name>Spring snapshots</name>
 *     <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
 *     <snapshots>
 *       <enabled>true</enabled>
 *     </snapshots>
 *   </repository>
 * </repositories>
 *
 * @author Paul Samsotha
 */
public class RestAssuredDocs extends JerseyTest {
    
    @Rule
    public final RestDocumentation restDocumentation 
            = new RestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");
    
    public static class TestBean {
        public int id;
        public String message;
        public TestBean (){}
        public TestBean(int id, String message) {
            this.id = id;
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
    
    @Path("test")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public static class TestResource {
        
        @PUT
        @Path("{id}")
        public TestBean update(TestBean bean) {
            return bean;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class)
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
    }
    
    private final int port = 9998;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    @Test
    public void examplePut() throws Exception {
        TestBean bean = new TestBean(1, "a message");
        given().port(this.port)
                .filter(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                .filter(document("example-put", 
                        requestFields(
                                fieldWithPath("id").description("The id"),
                                fieldWithPath("message").description("The message")
                        ),
                        responseFields(
                                fieldWithPath("id").description("The id"),
                                fieldWithPath("message").description("The message")
                        ),
                        pathParameters(
                                parameterWithName("id").description("The id")
                        )
                ))
                .contentType("application/json")
                .accept("application/json")
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(bean))
                .put("/test/{id}", "1")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("id", equalTo(1))
                .body("message", equalTo("a message"));
    
    }
}
```

For more examples on how to use REST Assured, visit the [User Guide](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage)

---

### UPDATE 2

**I** just release an implementation for Jersey. You can find the project **[here](https://github.com/RESTDocsEXT/restdocsext-jersey)**. Basic usage is seen below. See the wiki in the project for more information

**Dependency**

```
<properties>
    <your.jersey.version>2.23</your.jersey.version>
    <restdocsext.jersey.version>0.1.0</restdocsext.jersey.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.restdocsext</groupId>
        <artifactId>restdocsext-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>${restdocsext.jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${your.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${your.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${your.jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Example**

```
// Other imports excluded for brevity
import static io.github.restdocsext.jersey.JerseyRestDocumentation.document;
import static io.github.restdocsext.jersey.JerseyRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.Preprocessors.preprocessRequest;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.Preprocessors.removeHeaders;

public class SimpleDocumentation extends JerseyTest {

    @Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation documentation 
            = new JUnitRestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @GET
        public String getSimple() {
            return "SimpleTesting";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void getSimple() {
        final Response response = target("test")
                .register(documentationConfiguration(this.documentation)) 
                .register(document("get-simple", 
                        preprocessRequest(removeHeaders("User-Agent")))) 
                .request()
                .get();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
        assertThat(response.readEntity(String.class), is("SimpleTesting"));
    }
}
```